# vba loop through all the pivot fields of a pivot table and return specified values

Tags: vba, loops, boolean, pivot

I have a dataset whose entries has 5 different attributes and one value. For example, I have a height of 5000 people. For each person I have his hair color, eye color, his nationality, the city he were born and the name of his mother (the 5 dimensions).

No/Eye Color/Hair Color/Nationality/Hometown/Mother's Name/Height

1. Blue        Blond        Swiss         Zürich     Nicole          184
2. Blue        Brown        English       York       Ruby            164
3. Brown       Brown        French        Paris      Sophie          154
4. etc..

So there are 5 dimensions. The data is set dynamically, so the number of categories in each dimensions can vary. I sought to compute the average height of people depending on whether I want to include some dimensions or not (from 1 to 5). For example I wanted the retrieve:

The average height of French and Blue eyed people. Next day only the people born in London. And the week after, the Swiss, blue-eyed, red-haired, born in Geneva and whose mother is called Nicole.

So I create a pivot table with the Eye Color as Row labels, Hair Color as Column labels, the  average height as the Data and the last 3 dimensions as Market Filters. This allowed me see all the possible and desired combinations of average height that my data implies.

**Now my goal is:**

I want to create a Macro that goes through all the possible combinations that my dimensions entails (i.e 2^5-1=31) and store in a vector all the combination of height average that are above a certain value, e.g. 190. And then It could print on a worksheet.

I was thinking on using some booleans arrays vector and For-Each-Next structure, but I must say that I fail to picture how to implement it.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the time and help!